# R separating out number and units from a column in a dataframe

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe which contains a column that has numbers as well as variable units:

```
 num <- c(1:5)
 val <- c("5%","10K", "100.2mv","1.4g","1.007kbars")

 df <- data.frame(num,val)
 df
```

How can I create two new columns from df$val, one that contains just the number and one the units?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
df$extr_nums <- str_extract(val, "\\d+\\.?\\d*")
df$extr_units <- str_replace(val, nums, "")
df
  num        val extr_nums extr_units
1   1         5%         5          %
2   2        10K        10          K
3   3    100.2mv     100.2         mv
4   4       1.4g       1.4          g
5   5 1.007kbars     1.007      kbars
```

The regexp is translated as: "at least 1 digit, followed by optional dot, followed by optional digits".